# Interpreting random slopes equal to 0 using lmer in R

Tags: r, mixed-model, lme4-nlme

I have just started working with mixed models and the lme4 package and was after some advice interpreting some results. I have a data set looking at the change in nest height of birds (NAP) over time (Year). I have two random effects that are relevant to my data; the area where the birds nest (Area) and the identity of the birds (MaleID).

I started by fitting a simple mixed model with random slopes for MaleID, as this is most relevant to my question.

```
ELEV.LME<-lmer(NAP~Year+(0+Year|MaleID),data=ELEV)
```

This model works fine and shows some variance in the slopes of MaleID. However, I also know that Area and possibly random intercepts of MaleID are also important. I fitted a new model including area;

```
ELEV.LME2<-lmer(NAP~Year+(0+Year|MaleID)+(1|Area),data=ELEV)
```

but now the variance for random slopes in MaleID is 0. The same issue occurs if I include random intercepts for MaleID;

```
ELEV.LME4<-lmer(NAP~Year+(1|MaleID)+(0+Year|MaleID),data=ELEV)
```

I originally thought this may be caused by having cases of MaleID that only occur once in the data set, but I received the same 0 value when these were removed. Is this 0 value caused by my coding or a structural issue with my data? Or does this result tell me that variation in the slopes of MaleID explains none of the variance in NAP over Years? I wasn't expecting a large variance in random slopes, but 0 seems quiet strange, especially as I received the same result after I change around the dataset. Any help or advice would be greatly appreciated. Thank you!

I have included a dput() output from a subset of my data below. The real data set is thousands of records, and has many more levels of Area, but I encounter the same result with this reduced data set.

```
structure(list(MaleID = c(1003L, 1010L, 1113L, 1113L, 1113L, 
1113L, 1113L, 1113L, 1113L, 1113L, 1113L, 1113L, 1113L, 1113L, 
1167L, 1167L, 1167L, 1168L, 1168L, 1168L, 1200L, 1207L, 1207L, 
1216L, 1216L, 1216L, 1216L, 1216L, 1216L, 1216L, 1223L, 1223L, 
1240L, 1240L, 1240L, 1240L, 1240L, 1240L, 1240L, 1257L, 1257L, 
1299L, 1300L, 1300L, 1301L, 1302L, 1302L, 1310L, 1312L, 1327L, 
1327L, 1327L, 1330L, 1347L, 1347L, 1347L, 1347L, 1347L, 1347L, 
1347L, 1347L, 1347L, 1379L, 1390L, 1393L, 1393L, 1393L, 1393L, 
1393L, 1393L, 1393L, 1393L, 1404L, 1404L, 1420L, 1420L, 1420L, 
1420L, 1420L, 1420L, 1425L, 1440L, 1440L, 1449L, 1449L, 1449L, 
1449L, 1449L, 1449L, 1449L, 1449L, 1449L, 1452L, 1452L, 1454L, 
1454L, 1465L, 1465L, 1465L, 1465L, 1466L, 1488L), Year = c(1995L, 
1995L, 1995L, 1996L, 2008L, 2010L, 2010L, 2011L, 2011L, 2012L, 
2012L, 2012L, 2013L, 2013L, 1995L, 1996L, 1996L, 2008L, 2010L, 
2011L, 1995L, 1995L, 1996L, 2008L, 2010L, 2011L, 2011L, 2012L, 
2012L, 2013L, 1995L, 1995L, 2008L, 2008L, 2010L, 2011L, 2011L, 
2012L, 2013L, 1996L, 2008L, 1995L, 1995L, 1996L, 1996L, 1996L, 
1996L, 1996L, 1996L, 1996L, 2008L, 2010L, 1996L, 2008L, 2008L, 
2010L, 2011L, 2011L, 2012L, 2012L, 2012L, 2013L, 1996L, 1995L, 
1995L, 1995L, 1996L, 2008L, 2008L, 2010L, 2011L, 2011L, 1995L, 
1995L, 1996L, 1996L, 2008L, 2010L, 2010L, 2010L, 1996L, 1995L, 
1995L, 1995L, 1996L, 2008L, 2010L, 2010L, 2011L, 2011L, 2011L, 
2012L, 1995L, 1996L, 1996L, 1996L, 1995L, 1995L, 1995L, 1995L, 
1996L, 1995L), Area = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L), .Label = c("A", 
"B"), class = "factor"), NAP = c(158L, 144L, 144L, 150L, 149L, 
155L, 143L, 140L, 147L, 140L, 132L, 143L, 137L, 141L, 147L, 155L, 
138L, 140L, 190L, 163L, 144L, 139L, 138L, 144L, 147L, 142L, 135L, 
136L, 141L, 144L, 153L, 149L, 135L, 143L, 209L, 144L, 220L, 138L, 
185L, 135L, 136L, 189L, 182L, 145L, 189L, 138L, 184L, 149L, 150L, 
157L, 178L, 187L, 190L, 147L, 145L, 149L, 145L, 166L, 140L, 138L, 
144L, 143L, 158L, 138L, 140L, 135L, 142L, 134L, 152L, 153L, 142L, 
198L, 169L, 142L, 151L, 160L, 160L, 163L, 153L, 153L, 141L, 136L, 
148L, 142L, 175L, 153L, 144L, 162L, 168L, 169L, 142L, 154L, 139L, 
129L, 161L, 166L, 162L, 134L, 159L, 152L, 138L, 152L)), .Names = c("MaleID", 
"Year", "Area", "NAP"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-102L))
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It seems like you are at the model building stage. The following is just to get you started and incomplete.

First of all, I suggest to transform your `Year` variable as the zero for this variable is pretty arbitrary. It might make more sense (without knowing anything about the background of the data) to let it start with 0:

```
ELEV$Year1 <- ELEV$Year-min(ELEV$Year)
```

Now, standard advice is that you should always plot your data:

```
library(ggplot2)
p1 <- ggplot(ELEV, aes(x=Year1, y=NAP, colour=factor(MaleID))) + 
  geom_point(size=4) + guides(colour=guide_legend(ncol=3)) + facet_wrap(~Area, nrow=2)
print(p1)
```

[image]

This doesn't look promising. Nevertheless, let's use a model:

```
library(lme4)
ELEV.LME <- lmer(NAP~Year1+(0+Year1|MaleID),data=ELEV)
p1 + geom_line(data=cbind(ELEV, predNAP=predict(ELEV.LME)), aes(y=predNAP))
```

[image]

```
summary(ELEV.LME)
Linear mixed model fit by REML ['lmerMod']
Formula: NAP ~ Year1 + (0 + Year1 | MaleID) 
   Data: ELEV 

REML criterion at convergence: 865.583 

Random effects:
 Groups   Name  Variance Std.Dev.
 MaleID   Year1   0.4191  0.6473 
 Residual       268.8230 16.3958 
Number of obs: 102, groups: MaleID, 33

Fixed effects:
            Estimate Std. Error t value
(Intercept) 151.4929     2.4583   61.63
Year1         0.2349     0.3137    0.75

Correlation of Fixed Effects:
      (Intr)
Year1 -0.548
```

As you see, your random slope hardly explains any of the variance and the model as a whole performs very poorly. We could now try to add a random intercept grouped by MaleID, but let's try a random intercept grouped by area instead:

```
ELEV.LME1 <- lmer(NAP~Year1+(0+Year1|MaleID)+(1|Area),data=ELEV)
p1 + geom_line(data=cbind(ELEV, predNAP=predict(ELEV.LME1)), aes(y=predNAP))
```

[image]

Is this better? Let's check:

```
anova(ELEV.LME,ELEV.LME1)
Data: ELEV
Models:
ELEV.LME: NAP ~ Year1 + (0 + Year1 | MaleID)
ELEV.LME1: NAP ~ Year1 + (0 + Year1 | MaleID) + (1 | Area)
          Df    AIC    BIC  logLik deviance Chisq Chi Df Pr(>Chisq)
ELEV.LME   4 876.31 886.81 -434.15   868.31                        
ELEV.LME1  5 877.56 890.68 -433.78   867.56 0.752      1     0.3859
```

Model performance is pretty much equal, so the simpler model would be more appropriate.

There are many additional aspects to be considered. In particular you'd need to check assumptions, most importantly distribution of residuals and variance homogeneity.

You would now need to continue trying to finde the appropriate random effects (and also use some understanding of the study setup for this, which was not available to me). In the end, you could try to derive confidence intervals or p-values. However, I don't believe that a linear model is going to be useful with this data.

Comment: Thanks for the quick response. Succinct summary of model fitting! Transforming Year to 0 seems to have solved much of the problems, as I now get a non-zero result for random slopes. 

So in general, if I encounter a model output where the variance of a random effect is 0.0 and a Std.Dev of 0.0 does this imply some issue with the model? Or does this occur often in working models?

Comment: If the variance explained by a random effect is extremely small in comparison to the residual variance, that should definitely investigated.